# How to use choose like if else condition in xslt

Tags: c#, linq, xslt, dataset

Hi people anyone who understand xslt well can you please help me.
I just want to display the checkbox, if got value checkbox must be checked else not checked. I used choose but it not giving me what I want. It just give me only checked checkbox.

**Here is my C# code**

```
  public DataSet printIST(long Id)
    {
        var query0 = (from request in _entities.ISTMotivations
                        select new
                        {
                            ISTID = request.ISTID,
                            ISTMotivation = request.ISTReason.LookupDesc,
                            ISTMotivationID = request.ISTMotivationID,
                            ISTReasonID = request.ISTReasonID
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.ISTReasonID);
        var query2 = (from request in _entities.ISTMotivations
                        where request.ISTID==Id
                        select new
                        {
                            ISTMotivationID=request.ISTMotivationID,
                            ISTID=request.ISTID,
                            ISTReasonID=request.ISTReasonID
                        }).OrderBy(x=>x.ISTReasonID);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(query0.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table4";
        ds.Tables.Add(query2.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Table5";
        return ds;
    }
```

**Here is my XSLT code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:key name ="keyMoticationID" match ="NewDataSet/Table4" use ="ISTMotivationID"/>
      <xsl:key name ="keycheck" match ="NewDataSet/Table5" use ="concat(ISTID, '+',ISTMotivationID)"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
          <html>
            <xsl:variable name="lst4" select="//NewDataSet/Table4" />
            <xsl:variable name="lst5" select="//NewDataSet/Table5" />
            <style>
              TABLE {empty-cells: show; border-spacing: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;width:100%;}
              .pagebreak {page-break-after: always;}
              TD.HeaderText {font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;border:0;margin:0;background:none;font-weight:bold;}
              TR.HeaderText {font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;border:0;margin:0;background:none;font-weight:bold;}
              TR.NormalText {font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;border:0;margin:0;background:none;font-weight:normal;}
              TD.NormalText {font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;border:0;margin:0;background:none;font-weight:normal;}
              TABLE.SpacedRows TD {padding:2pt 0 8pt 0; vertical-align:top;}
              TABLE.NormalText {font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;border:0;margin:0;background:nonkeyIDe;font-weight:normal;}
            </style>
            <title>
              <center>Application for IST transfer</center>
            </title>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   width="100%" style="border-style:solid;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial;border-collapse: collapse;font-size:11px;" >
      <xsl:for-each select="$lst4[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyMoticationID', ISTMotivationID)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="intISTMotivationID">
          <xsl:value-of select="ISTMotivationID" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:2%; padding:2px;text-align:center;">
            <xsl:value-of select ="$lst4[ISTMotivationID=$intISTMotivationID]/ISTReasonID"/>
          </td>
          <td style="width:96%; padding:2px;">
            <xsl:value-of select ="$lst4[ISTMotivationID=$intISTMotivationID]/ISTMotivation"/>
          </td>

        <xsl:for-each select="$lst5[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keycheck',concat(ISTID,'+', $intISTMotivationID))[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="intISTID">
          <xsl:value-of select="ISTID" />
        </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$lst5[ISTID=$intISTID and ISTMotivationID=$intISTMotivationID]/ISTReasonID">
              <td valign="top" style="width:2%; padding:3px; text-align:center;">
                <input id="chkISTReasonID" name="ISTReasonID" type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input>
              </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <td valign="top" style="width:2%; padding:3px;text-align:center;">
                <input id="chkISTReasonID" name="ISTReasonID" type="checkbox"></input>
              </td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
      </html>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:choose ... >` is what you're after, but without knowing how you tried to use it it's difficult to know why you couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I don't know why is not displaying unchecked checkbox

Comment: The obvious answer is that it's because your test is always returning true - that node exists.  There's not enough information here to be able to replicate the issue unfortunately.

Try rewriting this as the smallest possible way of demonstrating the problem - take out a lot of the irrelevant code, include the XML, etc.

Comment: The reason you do not see the checkbox from the otherwise is clearly because your test condition is truethy!

Comment: @sidneydobber okay can you write the little example how can I resolve this please?

Comment: @Dlamini.M Please post a **reproducible** example, including the XML input - preferably minimized to only what's necessary to reproduce the problem. See: [mcve]

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have edited my question I used C# code

Comment: @Dlamini.M The keys are "minimized" and "reproducible". The code you have posted includes lots of unnecessary detail, and more importantly is *not* sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Problem solved guys thank you I did came up with the solution I just did a left join in my query and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve I just performed a left join in my query and it working.

```
 var query2 = (from a in _entities.ISTReasons
                      join b in _entities.ISTMotivations on new { col1 = a.ISTReasonID, col2 = Id } equals new { col1 = b.ISTReasonID, col2 = b.ISTID }
                      into tmp1
                      from c in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                      {
                          ISTReasonID = a.ISTReasonID,                        
                          ReasonDesc = a.LookupDesc,
                          ReasonCode = a.LookupCode,
                          Checked = c.ISTMotivationID != null ? "Y" : "N"
                      });
```